# How to set a date restriction for returned events in Google Calendar and put them in order - Python

Tags: python, events, google-calendar-api

Ok, so I've seen similar questions to this, but most of them are in regards to different languages, none seem to be within the realm of Python.  I've also searched the documentation on Google for the different options with listing events in a Calendar.  There is no method listed by Google to restrict the results by order of state date, only start time.

So, I was hoping someone could help me with a way to retrieve events from a calendar get them in order, and at the same time, restrict the results to a specific date.  Preferably I'd like to not get any events farther than 30 days out and order them by start time and date.  My guess, while I'm not sure of the best way to do it, would be to get all the events, put them in a list or dictionary maybe, then maybe enumerate that list or dictionary into the order I want and then do some if statements to remove anything from the list or dictionary that's farther than 30 days out.  Below is the code I'm using and then the response I get in the terminal.  As you can see I get dates that are a year out and they're all out of order.  Oh and just so you aren't confused, this code is pulling from multiple parts of my overall calendar in Google.  Additionally, you'll notice I limited the results to a maximum of 5 to make testing easier so I wasn't returning 100's of results.

```
try:
  #  -----  Facebook Birthday Calendar  -----
  page_token = None
  interval = 0
  while True:
    events = service.events().list(calendarId='my calendar id', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for event in events['items']:
      if interval < 5:
    dt = dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['date'])
    print event['summary'], dt.strftime('%d %m %Y')
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
    interval += 1
  else:
    break
    if not page_token:
  break
print "-----"

#  -----  My Gmail Calendar  -----
page_token_two = None
interval_two = 0
while True:
  events_two = service.events().list(calendarId='my calendar id', pageToken=page_token_two).execute()
  for event_two in events_two['items']:
    if interval_two < 5:
  dt_two = dateutil.parser.parse(event_two['start']['dateTime'])
  dstime_two = dateutil.parser.parse(event_two['start']['dateTime'])
  detime_two = dateutil.parser.parse(event_two['end']['dateTime'])
      print event_two['summary'] + " " + dt_two.strftime('%d %m %Y') + " " + dstime_two.strftime('%H%M') + "-" + detime_two.strftime('%H%M')
      # print event_two['summary'], dt_two.strftime('%d %m %Y')
  page_token_two = events_two.get('nextPageToken')
  interval_two += 1
else:
  break
  if not page_token_two:
break
print "-----"

#  -----  US Holidays Calendar  -----
page_token_three = None
interval_three = 0
while True:
  events_three = service.events().list(calendarId='my calendar id', pageToken=page_token_three).execute()
  for event_three in events_three['items']:
    if interval_three < 5:
  dt_three = dateutil.parser.parse(event_three['start']['date'])
  print event_three['summary'], dt_three.strftime('%d %m %Y')
  page_token_three = events_three.get('nextPageToken')
  interval_three += 1
else:
  break
  if not page_token_three:
break
print "-----"
```

Results:

```
Person's Birthday 17 03 2014
Person's Birthday 20 09 2013
Person's Birthday 10 09 2013
Person's Birthday 17 04 2014
Person's Birthday 29 04 2014
-----
Work 12 04 2013 1430-2330
Work 15 04 2013 1415-2315
Work 22 04 2013 1415-2315
Work 25 04 2013 1405-2305
Work 29 04 2013 0640-0230
-----
Patriot Day 11 09 2012
Thanksgiving 28 11 2013
Groundhog Day 02 02 2014
Memorial Day 28 05 2012
Lincoln's Birthday 12 02 2013
-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python datetime objects are very easy to work with. For instance, you could collect your event and datetime information into a list of tuples, like this:

```
all_events = []
for <loop over events from server>:
    all_events.append((dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['date']), event['summary']))
```

And then you can filter and sort those tuples, using the fact that you can add/subtract datetimes and get timedelta objects. You can simply compare to a timedelta object which represents a difference of 30 days:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

max_td = timedelta(days=30)
now = datetime.now()

# Remove events that are too far into the future
filtered_events = filter(lambda e: e[0] - now <= max_td, all_events)

# Sort events in ascending order of start time
filtered_events.sort()
```

Comment: I've been constantly editing/removing my comments as I continued to find errors in what I was doing.  In the end I achieved what I wanted thanks to your help.  Much appreciated.